# Creating SignedURL for uploading multiple files

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, signed-url

For now I'm able to create signed url for uploading file to gcp storage.
Is it possible to create one signed url for many files?
Below is Golang implementation for single file:

```
opts := &storage.SignedURLOptions{
    GoogleAccessID: googleCfg.Email,
    PrivateKey:     googleCfg.PrivateKey,
    Scheme:         storage.SigningSchemeV4,
    Method:         http.MethodPut,
    Expires:        time.Now().Add(168 * time.Hour),
    ContentType:    contentType,
}

url, err := storage.SignedURL(bucketName, folderName+filePath, opts)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with multiple files? A signed url has a specific object name in it, would these multiple files overwrite the same object every time? I think the premise of the question is weird,  but the short answer is probably "no, you can't".

Comment: Question is not weird. Maybe I was not prefectly accurate. I want to upload many files and It could be uploaded on different paths. Maybe it is not possible.

Comment: Signed URLs are object specific. You must create a Signed URL for each object.